# how can you detect if the position clicked is correct?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a find waldo and to do that, I need to assign a position in where the character is located. To do this, I've thought of assigning the position of the X and Y with e.pageX and e.PageY, the problem is that the image is very big so yo need to scroll to see all the image.

So the position changes each time I scroll. I've been thinking a way of checking if the character clicked is correct but I can't seem to find a way to do that... If anyone could help me please I woild really appreciate it.

Here is the code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import mainImage from '../img/marioBrosMain.jpg'
import '../main.css'
import Box from '../pages/box.js'

function Main() {

  const [style, setStyle] = useState();
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true)
  let Characters;

  const imageClick = (x, y) => {
    const newStyle = {
      position: "absolute",
    zIndex: 2,
    borderRadius: "2px solid red",
    border: "4px solid red",
    height: "50px",
    paddingLeft: "10px",
    left: `${x}px`,
         top: `${y}px`
          }
          setHidden(false)
    return newStyle

  }

  if (!hidden) {
Characters = (
    <>
    <div className="hello">
      <div>
        <button>Star</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Mario</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Yoshi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
);
}
    return (
        <div id="frame">
          <div id="mainImage" style = {style}>
          {Characters}
          </div>
          <img src={mainImage} className="marioBros____image"  onClick={(e) => {setStyle(imageClick(e.pageX, e.pageY)); console.log(e.pageX)}} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main
```